# slideUp and slideDown animation does not work after first use

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, slidetoggle, dropdownbox

I have used jQuery to build something like a dropdown, but it only works for the first two clicks, and then it doesn't.  How can I make a dropdown? Can it be done with a loop? (I have not learnt loop yet, so any solution would work.)

For Each SLIDEUP and SLIDEDOWN I wanted to make different TIME....

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".click-on").click(function() {
    jQuery(".box").slideUp(2000, function() {
      jQuery(".click-on").click(function() {
        jQuery(".box").slideDown(500);
      });
      return false;
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="fan">THIS IS A FAN</p>
<p id="gun">THIS IS A GUN</p>

<p class="click-on">Click Here</p>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks For The Edit, I Could not Do that Correctly... I Am Really Sorry for that.

Comment: The issue is because you're nesting your events. That's a *really* bad idea. Every time you click on the `click-on` element you're adding another slideUp call, which adds another `click` and adds another slideDown. Separate your events.

Comment: Can I Add any LOOP like Feature????? Although I Do not Even Learnt to MAKE LOOPS yet

Comment: Firstly, just FYI you don't need to capitalise every word, and writing in all caps is considered rude as it's interpreted as shouting. To answer your question, you don't need any loops for this. See the answers below for much better implementations.

Comment: I would also suggest - and I say this without intending to be insulting, we all had to start somewhere (I personally had no coding experience at all less than 2 years ago) - that you should learn the very basics of programming (like loops, conditional statements, functions etc.) before you try to make webpages. You don't need to be an expert by any means to make some simple interactive sites with javascript, but you do need to know these basics.

Comment: Yeah, I Appreciate That From You ROBIN and RORY..... I was Getting Started JS After I completed some PSD to HTML using different CSS Frameworks - Bootstrap, UIKit. But When I started JS and saw many examples made using JS, I saw LOOP, And that is why I mentioned "How to solve with loop" in my Question. But As I am a Begginer, Any Solution is Fine... I Think you will understand, SIR......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you misunderstand the meaning of the `.click()` function.

`.click()` sets the handler function each time when the click event is triggered from the selected DOM.

Since you have called another `.click()` within the callback of `.slideUp()`, you are actually replacing the handler function. In your current logic, the obvious fix is to do infinite callback after each click like:

```
jQuery(".click-on").click(function(){
    jQuery(".box").slideUp(2000, function(){
        jQuery(".click-on").click(function(){
            jQuery(".box").slideDown(500,function(){
                jQuery(".click-on").click(function(){ 
                    jQuery(".box").slideUp(2000, function(){//Repeating callbacks... ...
            });
        });
    });
});
```

and seriously it is very bad. Such implementation should not be done.

Instead, it is better for you to have a conditional checking for each click, so the logic will determine itself either `.slideUp()` or `.slideDown()` should be called. It should be like

```
$(".click-on").click(function(){//you can also use $ instead of jQuery
    //do some conditional check here
    if(isSlidedUp)$(".box").slideDown(1000);
    else $(".box").slideUp(1000)
});
```

or even better you use `.slideToogle()`.

```
$(".click-on").click(function(){
    $(".box").slideToggle(1000)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to achieve something like that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".click-on").click(function(){
    $('.box').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsrc9mbd/1/

Comment: But, now the Timing is same for BOTH SLIDE-UP and SLIDE-DOWN..........I Was trying to achive Different Timing for each of them. SLIDE-UP:- 2s   SLIDE-DOWN:-0.5s

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @hetious is what I would have given - but having just seen the comment that slide-up and slide-down should have different times, you'll have to do this instead. Basically, check when you click whether the box is visible or not, and either slideUp or dlideDown accordingly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".click-on").click(function() {
    var box = jQuery(".box");
    if (box.is(":visible")) {
      box.slideUp(2000);
    }
    else {
      box.slideDown(500);
    }
  });
);
```

(Note that I have extracted a variable for `jQuery(".box")`, just to save some typing. And you can also use `$` as an alias for `jQuery` to save yet more (the only reason this wouldn't work is if you are using another library which defines a global `$` variable, which a few do.)